# Connection to remote location WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, directory, download

In my application I have to display all tours that are provided by my agency. This tours are KML files exported from google maps, and reside on their server. I want to get all the file names in that directory and then download the requested one to the phone. How can I achieve this task? I'm new to WP8 development. Background file transfer was an option, but using this technique, I can't get the file names from there. Could you suggest what would be the best way to accomplish this task?

Comment: I want to get list of file names, so the user can download desired ones. How can I get that file names?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a wp8 dev issue. If you were using ASP or PHP how would you go about this? The directory would need to be exposed somehow perhaps via a web service or ftp. Something... Is this first issue already addressed? If so, how?

Comment: it's exactly the wp8 issue it doesn't support ftp, and web service that feature is also unsupported. I thought there would be someone who already had this issue and got some workaround

Comment: so are you saying this is an ftp site? Please be specific on how this server is accessed.

Comment: ftp is supported on that site. What I want is how to access remote folder from wp any ways possible and after that I will ask them to reconfigure the server

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you don't have a WebService.

You can keep another file that keeps a list of file names available on your server and get this single file whenever you need the names of all the files. But you will have to keep this file updated at all times, whenever your list of files (KML) changes.

A better approach will be to have a WebService that could have GetAllFileNames() and GetFile(string fileName) APIs.